# Proving Sequent using Natural Deduction

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

**RTP**: $P \to Q, R \to \neg Q, (S\to \neg P)\to R \vdash (\neg T ∨ P)\to(T \to S)$ using primitive rules of natural deduction. I've attempted this question multiple times but keep getting stuck on trying to get $S$ so I can use a couple arrow introductions to get the conclusion.

**Attempt**:

1 (1) $P \to Q$ Assumption

2 (2) $R \to \neg Q$ Assumption

3 (3) $(S\to \neg P)\to R$ Assumption

4 (4) $(\neg T ∨ P)$ Assumption

5 (5) $T$ Assumption

4,5 (6) $P$ $4,5∨$E

1,4,5 (7) $Q$ $1,6\to$E

8 (8) $S$ Assumption

9 (9) $S\to \neg P$ Assumption

8,9 (10) $\neg P$ Assumption

4,5,9 (11) $\neg T$ 6,10RAA(8)

12 (12) R Assumption

2,12 (13) $\neg Q$ $2,12\to$E

1,2,4,5 (14) $~R$ 7,13RAA(12)

I realise now that I've eliminated almost all the necessary assumptions with only line 9 left over (those at lines 4 and 5 which will be eliminated via arrow introduction for the conclusion once I have $S$), but I don't know how I can proceed from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using "primitive rules" of [Natural Deduction](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4).

From line (4) $(¬T ∨ P)$ --- Assumption, we apply $(\lor \text E)$ with two sub-proofs:

The first one is straightforward:

5. $\lnot T$ --- assumed [a] for $(\lor \text E)$
6. $T$ -assumed [b]
7. $\bot$ --- from 5) and 6) using $(\lnot \text E)$
8. $S$ --- from 7) using $(\bot \text E)$

> 9. $(T \to S)$ --- from 6) and 8) by $(\to \text I)$, discharging [b].

The second sub-proof:

10. $P$ --- assumed [d] for $(\lor \text E)$
11. $Q$ --- from 10) and 1) by $(\to \text E)$
12. $R$ --- assumed [e]
13. $\lnot Q$ --- from 12) and 2) by $(\to \text E)$
14. $\bot$ --- from 11) and 13) by $(\lnot \text E)$
15. $\lnot R$ --- from 12) by $(\lnot \text I)$, discharging [e]
16. $(S \to \lnot P)$ --- assumed [f]
17. $R$ --- from 16) and 3) by $(\to \text E)$
18. $\bot$ --- from 15) and 17) by $(\lnot \text E)$
19. $\lnot (S \to \lnot P)$ --- from 16) and 18) by $(\lnot \text I)$, discharging [f]
20. $\lnot S$ --- assumed [g]
21. $S$ --- assumed [h]
22. $\bot$ --- from 20) and 21) by $(\lnot \text E)$
23. $\lnot P$ --- from 22) by $(\bot \text E)$
24. $(S \to \lnot P)$ --- from 21) and 23) by $(\to \text I)$, discharging [h]
25. $\bot$ --- from 19) and 24) by $(\lnot \text E)$
26. $S$ --- from 20) and 25) by $(\neg \neg \text E)$: if $\Gamma , \neg \varphi \vdash \bot$, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$, discharging [g]
27. $(T \to S)$ --- from 26) by $(\to \text I)$.

Now we have derived $(T \to S)$ in the two sub-proofs and we can close the $(\lor \text E)$:

28. $(T \to S)$ --- from 4), 9) and 27) discharging assumptions [a] and [c]

> $(\lnot T \lor P) \to (T \to S)$ --- from 4) and 28) by $(\to \text I)$.

---

Here is an alternative proof that uses [Disjunctive syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism#Formal_notation):

4. $(¬T ∨ P)$ --- Assumption
5. $T$ --- assumed [a]
6. $P$ --- from 4) and 5)

Now we insert lines 10)-26) above to get:

26. $S$

and we conclude with:

> $T \to S$ --- from 5) and 27) by $(\to \text I)$, discharging [a]

Comment: In line 8, how can you assume S from the contradictions of lines 5 and 6? We haven't got $\neg S$ anywhere?

Comment: @xavayey244 - using [$(\bot \text E) \ \bot \vdash \varphi$](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4).

Comment: @xavayey244 - in order to apply $(\lor \text E)$ to $(\lnot T \lor P)$ we have to derive $(T \to S)$ in both cases: (i) assuming $\lnot T$ and (ii) assuming $P$. This is the way the rule works.

Comment: I am also confused with line 27. You take $S$ from 26 to be the consequent, but need to discharge an assumption of $T$ to do $\to I$. Which line is this $T$ assumption from?

Comment: @xavayey244 - you can always discharge with $(\to \text E)$. If you need, add the assumption $T$ in line 26bis) and discharge it in 27).

Comment: Okay. Where was the assumption in line 5 discharged?

Comment: @xavayey244 - do you know [$(\lor \text E)$ rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) ? In your proof you referenced it in line (6): what is the form of the rule are you using ?

Comment: Yes. It is vel-elimination. Since $¬∨$ and $T$ are true, we know that $P$ must be true.

Answer (score 0):

The premise is a negation $\neg(S \to \neg P)$, so it is likely you need to perform negation elimination. For that you need to intermediately derive $S \to \neg P$, resulting in a contradiction from which you may infer anything.
That anything will be $S$, so you prove the conclusion by contradiction, assuming $\neg S$ earlier on and dropping that assumption in the last step.
Now you want to derive $S \to \neg P$; this is an implication, so you have to derive $\neg P$ from an assumption $S$. Given the other assumptions you have at your disposal, how do you think that subderivation can be plugged together?

Comment: I have realised the last two lines of my proof were incorrect, so I cannot go from here. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l|}\hline #1\\\hline#2\\\hline\end{array}~~}$

You seek to derive $S$ under the assumption of $T$, $\lnot T\vee P$, and the premises.

You can immediately derive $P$ and $Q$ using *disjunctive syllogism* and *modus ponens*.

Likewise you could there after derive $\neg R$ and $\neg(S\to\neg P)$ using *modus tollens*.

However, I'd rather use reduction to absurdity to derive $S$.

Discharge the necessary contradictions and you are done.

$$\fitch{~~1.~P\to Q\\~~2.~R\to\lnot Q\\~~3.~(S\to\lnot P)\to R}{\fitch{~~4.~\lnot T\lor P}{\fitch{~~5.~T}{~~6.~P\\~~7.~Q\\\fitch{~~8.~\lnot S}{\vdots\\14.~\lnot Q}\\15.~S}\\16.~T\to S}\\17.~(\lnot T\lor P)\to(T\to S)}$$

Using [logic.tamu.edu/daemon.html](https://logic.tamu.edu/daemon.html)

```
P->Q, R->~Q, (S->~P)->R |- (~TvP)->(T->S)
OK    1          (1)   P->Q           A         
OK    2          (2)   R->~Q          A         
OK    3          (3)   (S->~P)->R     A         
OK    4          (4)   ~TvP           A         
OK    5          (5)   T              A         
OK    4,5        (6)   P              4,5vE     
OK    1,4,5      (7)   Q              1,6->E    
OK    8          (8)   ~S             A         
:     :          :     :              :
OK    2,3,8      (14)  ~Q             ..,..->E   
OK    1,2,3,4,5  (15)  S              7,14RAA(8)
OK    1,2,3,4    (16)  T->S           15->I(5)  
OK    1,2,3      (17)  (~TvP)->(T->S) 16->I(4)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to prove it using only the primitive rules but thanks anyway :(

Comment: What set of rules do you call "primative"?  @xavayey244

Comment: There are 10. Assumption, caret-introduction, caret-elimination, vel-introduction, vel-elimination, arrow-introduction, arrow-elimination, reductio ad absurdum, double-arrow-introduction and double-arrow-elimination

Comment: This skeleton can be completed using the fundamental rules of natural deduction. (Gentzen's introduction/elimination rules for $\{\leftrightarrow,\to,\land,\lor,\lnot\}$ and double negation elimination, and explosion).  So it should be workable with yours.

Comment: When you assume $\neg S$ for reductio ad absurdum, you have ... in your proof indicating that it eventually leads to a contradiction. But I am confused with this part. How do you get to the contradiction?

Comment: Derive $\neg Q$ which contradicts the $Q$.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how you'd derive $\neg Q$ from $\neg S$. The only thing we seem to have that we can use is the third premise which has $S$ in it (not $\neg S$) so I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Can you not derive $S\to\neg P$ from $\neg S$ ?  $$\neg S\vdash S\to\neg P$$

Comment: I thought about this but you can't because arrow-elimination can only be applied to the main connective of a formula. In out case $S \to \neg P$ is the antecedant of $(S \to \neg P) \to R$, so to do this you'd need to get $\neg R$ to eliminate the main connective and get $S \to \neg P$ by itself.

Comment: No, you do not.  Under $\neg S$ you may derive $S\to\neg P$ by ${\to}$ *introduction*; **then** you may use ${\to}$ elimination to derive $R$, and $\neg Q$ in turn (citing $(S\to\neg P)\to R$ and $R\to\neg Q$ respectively).

Comment: I have been using https://logic.tamu.edu/daemon.html to check my answers. For example, if I have two assumptions $(A \to B) \to C$ and $\neg B$, then it doesn't let me deduce from arrow elimination $\neg A$. Arrow elimination is when you have a conditional and its antecedant, so you can conclude the consequent. I think what you're suggesting (a conditional and the negation of the consequent implies the negation of the antecedant) is a derived rule and is not arrow elimination.

Comment: Arrow **Introduction** $$\begin{array}{rlll}\text{Sequent attempted:}\\
  {\sim}S\vdash S\to{\sim}P\\
    OK &   1 &      (1) &  {\sim}S&             A         \\
    OK &   2 &      (2) &  S           &   A\\         
    OK &   3 &      (3) &  P           &   A\\         
    OK &   1,2 &     (4)&   {\sim}P     &        1,2\textsf{RAA}(3) \\
    OK &   1 &      (5) &  S\to{\sim}P  &        4{\to}\mathsf I(2) \end{array} $$

Comment: And the form you want is: $(A\to B)\to C$ and $\neg A$ allows you to derive $C$.$$\neg A,(A\to B)\to C\vdash C$$

Comment: 0 4! $$\def\neg{{\sim}}\def\to{{{-}\!\!{>}}}{\neg A,(A\to B)\to C\vdash C\\\boxed{\begin{array}{rlll}1&(1)&\neg A&\sf A\\2&(2)&(A\to B)\to C&\sf A\\3&(3)&A&\sf A\\4&(4)&\neg B&\sf A\\1,3&(5)&B&\sf 1,3RAA(4)\\1&(6)&A\to B&\sf 1{\to}I(3)\\1,2&(7)&C&\sf 6,2{\to}E\end{array}}}$$